# PHP comments guideline

Tags: php, phpstorm, sublimetext

I have seen many open source applications with some beautifully comment sections. something like the following snippet. Could anyone please tell me is there any plugin for phpstorm or sublimetext which can generate sections like this? or what this type of comments are called?

Thank you

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Blacklist Enabled
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| In order to invalidate tokens, you must have the blacklist enabled.
| If you do not want or need this functionality, then set this to false.
|
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if there is a plugin but you can easily create a new template by going to **Settings > Editor > Live Templates** (in Jetbrains products).

For example, I created a block comment template (`bcomm`) with two variables in `python`. Similarly, you could create a template for `php`.

[image]

Comment: Great thanks. I'll try live templates.